# Component linked to Page Meta is resolved to lowest page ranked inside Structure Group

Tags: dynamic-linking

If I link component in the Page Metadata and rendered using CT inside PT.
That Component Presentation is link is still resolved to the page.
But If i have this component on multiple pages then the dynamic link is getting resolved to lowest ranked page inside the structure group.
Ideally it should be the index or first ranked page inside the structure group?
Any reason why it is so?

I have not linked the component directly to any of the pages under Structure group. instead reading from parent i.e. structure group while publishing using Render Component Presentation inside Page template.

Comment: Wait, I wouldn't think dynamic linking could resolve your first scenario. Are you saying that linking to a Component referenced in Page Metadata (where the Component is not used anywhere else) creates a dynamic link to that page (resolved to a hyperlink on request)? I thought only Component Presentations (dynamic or static) on the page are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to understood how component link is getting resolved, if you understood this behavior then you will get your answer.

Basically a Component will always link to a Component that is rendered with a Component Template of the highest possible priority. You set the priority in Content Manager Explorer as a property of a Component Template. If a Component is used on more than one Page using different Component Templates with different priorities, the generated link will point to the Web page that contains the Component Presentation rendered with the highest-priority Component Template.

A link will be generated to a Component that uses a Component Template with the highest priority. In most cases, you will want to assign the highest priority to the Component Template that renders the most Component content.

There is good link available which you can go through for better understanding
http://www.albertteboekhorst.com/tridion_introduction/component-linking-in-sdl-tridion/

or You can visit sdllivecontent web site.

Comment: Hi Naresh, thanks for your reply. I understand the component linking behavior but i was finding the mechanism here bit off. As all the components are associated with same template (thus off course, same priority). Later comes the approach of finding the link via Page hierarchy, but here the link is not present on any particular page, as I am trying to resolve component link using a special class(or lets say servlet) and passing TCM Id as parameter to this class and and underneath calling GetComponentLinkUrl function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be mixing approaches here. If you want to create links to index pages or "first ranked" pages, consider creating either direct paths, urls, or page links using TOM.NET. The typical approach is a template to generate a navigation.xml or other sitempap file that contains these details.

On publish, you can resolve these links based on page publish status to a given publication target (e.g. only include links Published to Staging).

It looks like you understand both the priority and proximity rules but see my comment on Components in Page Metadata--I didn't think they'd be resolved in delivery. Otherwise, there's nothing identifying "high priority" pages such as `Index`.

If you extend linking, you might rely on naming conventions and how Web Application servers look for "index" pages (e.g. default.aspx, index.jsp, or index.html). Either way you probably want to template out page links in this case, rather than use dynamic (Component) linking (unless you actually add the Components to the pages' Component Presentation tab--in that case, I'd recommend XPM page types to help automate this).